# Any "MVC way" in Netbeans Platform?

Tags: model-view-controller, netbeans-7, netbeans-platform

I'm starting to develop on NBP and I just wanted to ask is there anything like NBP's way of MVC.

Because in cocoa you use subclasses of UIView and UIViewController or you can use xib's etc.
In Rails you also put your models, views and controllers in different directories.

So should I divide my code into part's by my self or NBP has also some dedicated classes that should be used.

Also maybe I shouldn't look for MVC if NBP offers some better patterns.

I'll be very thankful for answers, because I don't what to implement something that's already done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NetBeans platform is swing with some nifty additions, and If I recall Swing is design is [heavily influenced by MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29#Loosely-Coupled_and_MVC). So you should be pretty safe using MVC.

Alternatively I've been using the [Presentation Model pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html) recently (Both on and off the NetBeans platform). 
What is especially nifty is that the [JGoodies Binding Library](http://www.jgoodies.com/downloads/libraries.html) has [specific suppor](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/jgoodies/binding/2.0.6/binding-2.0.6-javadoc.jar!/index.html?com/jgoodies/binding/PresentationModel.html)t for the Presentation Model pattern

Comment: The NetBeans Platform itself is more 'DCI' oriented than MVC, I think. See, for instance, http://www.slideshare.net/guestb9a4bf/mvcdci-in-netbeans-by-jaroslav-tulach or http://www.antonioshome.net/kitchen/nbdci/